# Using PipeReader to read data in ASP.NET Core, how to discard old data?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, I develop a tcp server. I use `PipeReader` to receive data. Then I call `PipeReaderAdvanceTo(consumed, Examed);`.

At this time, the unconsumed data will be temporarily stored. I need to implement a function: if the next data packet reception time is greater than 10 seconds, the temporary data will be discarded and read from new data.

How can I implement this?